# How to query a second table for each result from a first table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm not really sure how to do this - I only posses a limited knowledge of joins in MySQL, and from what I read I don't think they'd be of much use here.

Essentially, I have 2 tables:

```
images                          votes
---------------------------     ------------------------------
image_id | name | square_id     vote_id | image_id | vote_type 
---------------------------     ------------------------------
1          img1   14            1         4          1
2          img2   3             2         17         0
3          img7   72            3         2          1
...                             ...
n          imgn   1478          n         n          1
```

What I'd like to do is get the details of each image and the **number of votes cast (plus the `vote_type`)** on each image where a certain condition is true (such as where each image has a certain `square_id`). Executing the first part of this query is easy:

```
SELECT `image_id`, `name` FROM `images` WHERE `square_id` = :boundParameter;
```

But, I'm unsure of how to get each `vote_id` and `vote_type` for each image that meets the original WHERE condition in my query.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Use a `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Welcome into the world of JOINs. You're bound to enter in a world of awesomeness on one hand and great pains on the others. A good start is here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: What pains? An even better start is here: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: Joins aren't often easily grasped and mastered by novices. At least, this is my experience.

Comment: Thanks for the links, fancyPants & STT LCU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a really simple join between tables. You really, really [should read this Q&A that I put together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables) about SQL and queries and joins between two tables.

In the meantime, this will probably give you what you want:

```
select
    img.image_id,
    img.name,
    img.square_id,
    count(vot.vote_id) as numberVotes,
    vot.vote_type
from
    images img
        join votes vot
            on img.image_id=vot.image_id
group by
    img.image_id,
    img.name,
    img.square_id,
    vot.vote_type
```

So, with that, first off, you don't want multiple queries, you want to use one query here. Running multiple connections/queries to a database is a MUCH higher overhead than running one query that fetches all the data you want.

Comment: Thanks for the link and the explanation!

Comment: @Antilogical No problems, i know the link is around a thousand pages long, but really, take the time to read it - at the very least, the very first answer - I have the code there so that you can create the database and run/test the queries so that you really truly understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT images.image_id, images.name , votes.vote_id , votes.vote_type 
FROM images
LEFT JOIN votes ON images.image_id = votes.image_id
WHERE `square_id` = :boundParameter;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT images.image_id,
       images.name,
       votes.vote_id,
       votes.vote_type
FROM images
LEFT JOIN votes ON images.image_id = votes.image_id
WHERE images.square_id = :boundParameter;
```